# How to use MessageEventInit with window.addEventListener

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I am trying to register a webmessage channel using kotlin-js, but am unable to determine how to get access to the `MessageEventInit` type.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom/-message-event-init/index.html

The `window.addEventListener` method only exposes a generic `Event` type

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom.events/-event-target/add-event-listener.html

```
fun addEventListener(
    type: String,
    callback: EventListener?,
    options: dynamic = definedExternally)
fun addEventListener(
    type: String,
    callback: ((Event) -> Unit)?,
    options: dynamic = definedExternally)
```

This is what I've come up with so far, but am having a hard time building the project.

```
fun configureChannel() {
    val channel = MessageChannel()
    var jsPortOne = channel.port1
    var jsPortTwo = channel.port2

    window.addEventListener("message", {
    }, false)

    jsPortOne.addEventListener("message", {
        window.alert((it as MessageEvent).data.toString())
    }, false)

    jsPortTwo.addEventListener("message", {
        window.alert((it as MessageEvent).data.toString())
    }, false)

    jsPortOne.start()
    jsPortTwo.start()
}
```

My primary goal is to convert this file to Kotlin/JS and combine it with this kotlin android project

https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/cordova-alternative-pattern/blob/master/app/src/main/assets/js/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hunch was correct. I was able to get the project building and deployed. To use a `MessageEvent` type in Kotlin/JS you need to cast the event to `MessageEvent`

`val event = it as MessageEvent`

Here is a sample:

```
@JsName("configureChannel")
fun configureChannel() {
    console.log("Configuring channel")
    window.addEventListener("message", {

        val event = it as MessageEvent

        if (event.data != KEY_CAPTURE_PORT) {
            console.log("event.data: ${event.data}")
            inputPort.postMessage(event.data)
        } else if (event.data == KEY_CAPTURE_PORT) {
            console.log("assigning captured port")
            outputPort = event.ports[0]
        }
    }, false)

    inputPort.start()
    outputPort.start()
}
```